# PHP Displaying Duplicate jQuery Elements

Tags: php, jquery, session, jquery-mobile, redirect

I'm having issues of page element duplication after a successful login.  When logged in, the page loads but with duplicates of the buttons and footer.  Also, if I remove the jQuery data-role page element, I can see the login form behind the current page's elements.  I have attached the login and then the intended successful login page redirect (ignore the security issues).  Please let me know if I'm handling the sessions correctly to carry the username over and how to fix this duplication problem.  Let me know if more information is needed.

Login:

```
<?php
//start output buffering 
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="hourslog.css" TYPE="text/css">

<title>Login</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/shipshape.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con = mysql_connect('***','***','***');  
mysql_select_db("***")or die("cannot select DB");


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
// username and password sent from Form
$myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']);
$mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '" . $myusername . "' AND password = '" . $mypassword . "' AND block_status < 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$active=$row['active'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count>0)
{

$_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;

header("location: /androidIMFeed.php");
}
else
{
$error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
}
?>

<form action="" method="post" data-ajax="false">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/><br />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/><br/>
<input type="submit" value=" Submit "/><br />
</form>



</body>
</html>


<?php
//end output buffering
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Also note that there is an extra `</div>` tag just befoe `</body>` tag on your Feeds page

Comment: I removed that, but there's still the mess above.

Comment: Its because of this line `include_once('androidLogin.php');`, just remove that line and test

Comment: You are correct, but how do I make sure the username variable is able to pass and redirect the page if there is not a successful login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your `androidIMFeed.php`

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if ( !isset( $_SESSION['login_user'] ) ) {
    include_once('androidLogin.php');
    exit();
  }
  ob_start();
?>
```

instead of

```
<?php
ob_start();
//start output buffering 
include_once('androidLogin.php');
?>
```

Comment: Remember `mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli` extension instead http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php